# What desk chair do you use?

Tags: hardware

I'm thinking about getting a new desk chair and since a lot of us in the IT industry are sitting for a good part of the day, I was wondering what everyone here uses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There can be only one: [Aeron](http://www.hermanmiller.com/Products/Aeron-Chairs).

Comment: Looks really nice !

Comment: Our entire office is outfitted with these. I actually don't like them very much...

Comment: I want one. My chair sucks.

Comment: if you get an Aeron, make sure it has all the options. The base model can dig into your thighs if you sit forward on it. Otherwise, its a fine chair.

Answer (score 3):

I've always been an Aeron guy but recently have moved over to the Embody and much prefer them.

[image]

Comment: This is an excellent chair.  If you lean back at all then this is the chair for you.

Answer (score 3):

I personally hate mesh chairs so I went with a [SteelCase Leap](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001BQ4BBQ). Got both (one for work, one for home) of mine on Ebay for ~$500.

Comment: yes, go for a leap - they deserve it just for the fancy fancy website: http://www.steelcase.com/en/products/category/seating/task/leap/pages/overview.aspx - see the 'adjustability' section and the interactive user guide.

Answer (score 1):

The POS that was giving to me when I started here. It hurts me and I need to stand up and stretch every hour or so. It's costing them more in productivity than a new Aeron would cost.

Answer (score 1):

I've had an Aeron, a [HAG H09 Inspiration](http://www.ergodepot.com/HAG_H09_Inspiration_p/9220.htm) (which I loved), and my current [Knoll Generation](http://www.sithowyouwant.com/).  I can say without a doubt that the Aeron is the worse of the three.  The Knoll is cheaper than either, but still not cheap.

The only real answer is to go sit in a bunch of chairs and see which one you like best, preferably with the help of someone who knows ergonomics to set each one up correctly.  It's going to be pricey, but your back is worth it!

Answer (score 1):

[HÅG Capisco 8106](http://www.hag.dk/produkter/hag-capisco/hag-capisco-8106/) is one of the best you can get in my area. It has a unique design that makes it very comfortable to sit on, even when you have say back problems.

[HÅG Capisco 8106 http://www.hag.dk/ProductCatalog/Media/7/7685/hag-capisco-8106_medium.jpg](http://www.hag.dk/ProductCatalog/Media/7/7685/hag-capisco-8106_medium.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

A simple, wooden chair from a Swedish flat pack furniture retailer. I currently prefer it over anything else!

Answer (score 0):

My chair is a [steaming mound](http://dilbert.com/dyn/str_strip/000000000/00000000/0000000/000000/00000/2000/100/2161/2161.strip.sunday.gif) manufactured at the lowest cost possible from some dark recess of the Pacific Rim, and sold at a reasonable price.  It goes by the title "Old Dollar".

[A nice-looking but crappily-built chair http://static.www.odcdn.com/pictures/us/od/sk/lg/927472_sk_lg.jpg](http://static.www.odcdn.com/pictures/us/od/sk/lg/927472_sk_lg.jpg)

Think about this for a moment: the translation of "Old Money" (as it was originally intended to imply this was a banker's leather chair) was so poorly done that it came across as "Old Dollar".  I destroyed the first one (the seat came off the piston), and the second one has already had the piston go out, and the seat bolts are starting to shear off.  I hate the faux brass studs that were tacked onto the chair to make it look like the leather armrests were "done by hand" (it comes off cheesy as you can clearly see they're just free-floating tacks).

That being said, it's fairly comfortable when it isn't sunk to the bottom of the floor and wobbling around.